# Nutch Seed URLs

Tags: java, nutch, web-crawler

Is it possible to get URLs into **Nutch** directly from a database or a service etc. I'm not interested in the ways which data is taken from the database or service and written to seed.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This cannot be done directly with the default nutch codebase. You need to modify [Injector.java](http://www.java-frameworks.com/java/nutch/org/apache/nutch/crawl/Injector.java.html) to achieve that.

**EDIT:**

Try using [DBInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/db/DBInputFormat.html) : an [InputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html) that reads input data from an SQL table. You need to modify the [Inject](http://www.java-frameworks.com/java/nutch/org/apache/nutch/crawl/Injector.java.html) code here (line 3 in snippet below):

```
JobConf sortJob = new NutchJob(getConf());
sortJob.setJobName("inject " + urlDir);
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(sortJob, urlDir);
sortJob.setMapperClass(InjectMapper.class);
```

Comment: I examined the file you recommended and found the **job** does reading from seed file. Here, we need to enter a text like file for the **JobConf** and I don't want to get the DB results into a .txt as a middle step.Any suggestions?



    JobConf sortJob = new NutchJob(getConf());
    sortJob.setJobName("inject " + urlDir);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(sortJob, urlDir);
    sortJob.setMapperClass(InjectMapper.class);

Comment: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-hadoop/tree/2186ef3e0025f3fe4d6233a0eb4f9e6f815d86e4

Comment: Thank for the answer, but this requires Hadoop debugging. I examined it deeply, no clear and good solutions.